# How to display actual date and time in Visual Basic 2008 form?

Tags: date

I have a problem displaying the date and time in my form. In my code, I  can display the date and time from the date and time the form was loaded and then, it never changes.

For example the form was loaded by March 6, 2014 1:32:00 then, the form shows March 6, 2014 1:32:00 and never change even it is already March 6, 2014 1:40:00

This is my declaration:

```
 Dim todaysdate As String = String.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm}", DateTime.Now)
 curDatelbl.Text = todaysdate
```

Answer (score 0):

Place a timer control on the form, set it's interval to 1000 (1 second), and call your code in the timer's tick event.  Don't forget to enable the timer on form load (or whenever you want it to start ticking.)

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    todaysdate = String.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm}", DateTime.Now)
    Me.curTimelbl.Text = todaysdate 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Bradley... I followed what you said but then it is still not working  here is my code                                      Private Sub Timer1_Tick_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        curDatelbl.Text = todaysdate
    End Sub

Comment: You will need to recalculate `todaysdate` in the tick event also.

Comment: todaysdate = String.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm}", DateTime.Now)

Comment: The variable you are storing the date and time in is not updated "live".  It is only a snapshot of what the time was at the exact moment the line of code runs.  The code I gave you in the example updates that variable snapshot every second so that it remains accurate.

Answer (score 0):

This code shows good enough

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Me.curTimelbl.Text = TimeOfDay
End Sub

Private Sub login_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Timer1.Enabled = True
    Me.curDatelbl.Text = todaysdate
End Sub
```